# Prevent table row onclick event to fire when clicking button inside the row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table row with ONCLICK event (that toggles additional data below). Inside one of the row cells I have a button (when clicked is performing an AJAX action).
When I click on the button - the Row's onclick event also fires and what happens is that the additional data appears before the AJAX call completes (which is a bad behavior for me).
Any ideas how can I solve this elegantly? (without identifying and coding it into the row's onclick code)
Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Add an `event.stopPropagation();` to your buttons `click` handler. For more information, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation).

Comment: Directed me to the exact solution. Thanks!!

Comment: direct link for the lazy! - worked like a charm to disable the table rows event handler from firing, but still allows a link in the table data to be clicked !! - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

Comment: Awesome-Thanks, worked for `TypeScript` as well: `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Is there a nicer way to do this though? I don't want to have to go through and find all my buttons to add `stopProgation` to.

Answer (score 4):

If you dislike the javascript solution, in many cases a CSS solution is possible as well:

```
style="pointer-events: none;"
```

That will supress the `<tr>` onclick event.

However, in some cases I still had issues where it didn't seem to work.
In the majority of cases I just use the style above.

Comment: This was the answer I needed as the onclick method I was calling called other methods and event.stopPropagation(); stopped them being called as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can just do this instead:

```js
tbody.on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    let target = $(e.target);
    if (target.is('i') || target.is('button') || target.is('a') || target.hasClass('select-checkbox')) {
        return;
    }
    //your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Card_ID</th>
                <th>Card_Number</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="pointer-events: none;">
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>12345</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td><button style="pointer-events: auto;" type="button" id="Inactive" class="btn btn-sm"></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```